# What does the Navigation Sharepoint Sitemap/Breadcrumb use to populate links?

Tags: sharepoint, navigation

I am building several layered site and the breadcrumb is skipping in-between sites.

```
Main Site > Current Site
```

I would like it to show, as I've seen in other sites

```
Main Site > SubSite > Current Site
Main Site > SubSite > SubSubSite > Current Site
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each 'in-between' site

- go to *Site Setting* / *Look and Feel* block / *Top link bar*
- Click on *Stop Inheriting Links*

This will cause the sites to show up in the top bread-crumb bar, while breaking getting rid of the *Top link bar* links.